# How do I create an Other category in PowerBI Desktop?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, ranking

I am learning Power BI Desktop. I have a project already loaded for which I have created a
[pie chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u7hu.png)

As you can see, the data is currently divided into two years: 2022 and 2021.

I also have data for previous years that I want to include in the chart. Unfortunately, none of these years has a high number. So I want to group them all into an "Other" category.

I've already tried using the RANKX function as described [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Grouping-Data-into-Other-Category/m-p/999825/highlight/true#M474876) (where I copied and pasted the formula from the comment and replaced the field name with my own) and [here](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/power-bi-rankx-function/) (where I went through the article step by step using my own field names). I used the exact format shown in both the comment and the article:

```
Rank = RANKX('Table','Table'[Percent],,DESC,Dense)
```

(Table is the table name I am using and Percent is the column I am trying to rank.)

When I added the new column to a table, though, PowerBI automatically gave me a sum calculation. This calculation gave me a 1 in each column. When I asked it not to give me a sum, it said it could not display the visual and took me back to the calculation screen.

EDIT: Thanks for your help Kevin! [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3Lav.png) is the table I tried to draw from. I am an idiot sometimes.

EDIT 2: Now I am trying to use a different field in the formula:

```
Rank = RANKX('FactClaimActivity','FactClaimActivity'[DirectIncurredLoss_ITD])
```

(This is the original field that I tried to base Percent on)

My table looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydu9g.png) (Yes, I know that 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2020 have negative values and 2014 and 2015 have $0 values. I just want to show what the data is.)

EDIT 3: This time I am also getting an error when I type in the formula, which says "A single value for column 'DirectIncurredLoss_ITD' in table 'FactClaimActivity' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

I do not understand why it wants a *single result* for a formula that *ranks* the data points based on this field. That seems like it defeats the whole purpose of the formula.

Yet when I use the formula, I get the same result as last time! This column is in the Fixed decimal number format, and it does have many different values.

EDIT: I've found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74801104/in-powerbi-desktop-how-do-i-create-an-other-category?noredirect=1#comment132014624_74801104)

Comment: What is the type of the year column?

Comment: Ah. I just checked the table and now I see the problem. The table I was using had one row with three columns: Percent, Year and now Rank. So the only rank was 1 because there is only one row.

Comment: Well, did you solve the problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by using the original data, but now I've got another. See my upcoming edit.

Comment: Sorry that took so long

Answer (score 0):

```
New Category = IF('FactClaimActivity'[Rank]<=2,'FactClaimActivity'[LossYear],"Other")
```

The formula will help you get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks. I did check out the links above already.

Comment: Please accept the above answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: It does not. This was suggested in the first link in my original post and it did not work when I tried it then.

Comment: When I tried this formula, the resulting error message was: "Column 'LossYear' in table 'FactClaimActivity' cannot be found or may not be used in this expression."